# how to remove configurable product images on simple product select on pdp?

Tags: magento2

How to Remove Images of configurable product on swatch select. and re-append if no option is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/etc/view.xml

```
<vars module="Magento_ConfigurableProduct">
        <var name="gallery_switch_strategy">prepend</var>
</vars>
```

Replace with

```
<vars module="Magento_ConfigurableProduct">
    <var name="gallery_switch_strategy">replace</var>
</vars>
```

I hope it will help you.